# Availability of vegetarian food in Mongolia

Tags: international-travel, mongolia, dietary-restrictions

I am going to travel to Mongolia in 2021 if COVID-19 will be fine by that time.

The local travel company did promise everything that I may need during the tour in Mongolia. Could you please help me how is the food in Mongolia as I am a vegetarian. Is it ok for me to travel to Mongolia? Do I need to take my own food? Or are there enough vegetarian meal selections? Local travel agency says there is a no problem.

Answer (score 21):

[Traditional Mongolian food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolian_cuisine) is *very* heavy on meat, particularly mutton, which is found in virtually every dish.  However, Ulan Bator is large and cosmopolitan enough a city to offer vegetarian options as well, and on the tourist trail (Gorkhi-Terelj NP etc) tour companies can cater to vegetarian diets.  You would be well advised to cater your own food if you go off the beaten track though.

Comment: Vegan might be still hard "on the trail" though. I remember a very very very chewy immortal cheese as protein source.